# How to diagnose/fix slow file management on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: filesystems, windows-server-2012, raid-5

The setup is:

- FUJITSU PRIMERGY TX300 S7
- RAID Ctrl SAS 6g 5/6 512mb (d2616)
- Windows Server 2012 64 bit
- Volume C: RAID 1 (2 HDDs)
- Volume D: RAID 5 (8 HDDs)

The problem is:
When we do something with a large amount of files on volume `D:`, at first everything is OK, but after several minutes speed goes drastically down (if it's deleting - it goes from 100 files/sec to 1 file/sec; if it's copying - from 100 MB/sec to 15 MB/sec).
Sometimes volume `D:` becomes inaccessible (it is still visible in Explorer, but the used space bar disappears).
And sometimes the system freezes so hard - it even stops repying to pings.

We thought that it might be something to do with caching, but we can't disable it, we get the "`windows could not change the write-caching setting for the device`" error.

How do we diagnose/fix the problem? Please help

Comment: Please clarify your statement about D becoming inaccessible "...but the used space bar disappears". Also, what are you doing with the files on D? And have you checked for updated firmwares and drivers for the hardware?

Comment: > Please clarify your statement about D becoming inaccessible "...but the used space bar disappears".   

If you click "Computer" on the desktop, you see local disks and under the "Local disk (D:)" you see a bar (long rectangle), which shows how much space is used on this disk. And under this bar you see "XXX GB is free out of YYY GB". So all this disappers, only "Local disk (D:)" is left. While this happens, I cannot access disk D:.

Comment: It sounds as though you likely have a hardware problem. Volumes should not be rendered inaccessible during file transfers.